# Azure DevOps rest api - Get work item by custom field

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am currently migrating from tfs 2015 to Azure DevOps, and I would like to use the REST Api services to get work items. In TFS were an option to include custom fields as filter in the http query to list work items, (e.g. there are many work items with custom field 'otherId', i want to list all the work items which otherId field value equals to 5) but in the Azure Devops api documentation i cannot find description about how to do this.

If it is possible, could you give me an example?

Tried to google it, read devops api documentation but i have not found any solution

Comment: Please have a read over https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to improve your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query-by-wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP). Your request may be like this:

```
POST https://TFS_SERVER:PORT/PROJECT/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=7.1-preview.2

{
  "query": "Select [System.Id] From WorkItems Where [YourCustomPath.otherId] = 'OTHER_ID'"
}
```

Check the example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query-by-wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#examples

Additionally, check the API version here: [API and TFS version mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#api-and-tfs-version-mapping)